# How android store contact's vcard data?

Tags: android, android-contacts, android-contentprovider

Normally we use this code to read contact's v-card data.

```
 AssetFileDescriptor afd = context.getContentResolver().openAssetFileDescriptor(
            Uri.withAppendedPath(Contacts.CONTENT_VCARD_URI, lookupKey), "r");
```

where is v-card data stored physically? I looked at the contacts2.db and it's not there as well?

Does anybody know how `openAssetFileDescriptor` works?

Answer (score 0):

Android creates VCards when required,taking information using [Contacts APIS](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/contacts.html)
I dont think they are stored as VCards in internal memory.
You can go through [android.pim.vcard](https://code.google.com/p/android-vcard/source/browse/android-vcard/src2/android/pim/vcard/?r=8b0127551b10d3178b86ef1da49122108a6abf23) package and get further details
Look at VCardComposer.java ,VCardBuilder.java

Answer (score 0):

```
AssetFileDescriptor fd = mContext.getContentResolver()
                        .openAssetFileDescriptor(uri, "r");

                BufferedInputStream fips = new BufferedInputStream(
                        fd.createInputStream());
                byte[] byteOneLine = new byte[8*1024];
                while(fips.read(byteOneLine) != -1){
                    output_.write(byteOneLine);
                }
```

where output_ is a instance of OutputStream.

However, it will take a long long long time to execute "mContext.getContentResolver()openAssetFileDescriptor(uri, "r")".
when i have 600 contacts, it spend 20 seconds.

Looking for better method.

Answer (score 0):

Simple and clean way:

Check my answer here for more details: [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8566363/getting-all-contacts-as-vcard-in-android/22023028#22023028)

Code:

```
public ArrayList<String> getContactsAsVcards()
{
    ArrayList<String> vcards = new ArrayList<String>();
    VCardComposer vCardComposer = new VCardComposer(context);

    vCardComposer.init();

    do {
        String vCard = vCardComposer.createOneEntry();

        vcards.add(vCard);
    } while (!vCardComposer.isAfterLast());

    return vcards;

}
```